# How to get a contourline shape into ArcGIS or QGIS from an AutoCAD file

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, autocad

My question this time is about a request. I need to create an elevation profile and I know I can do that in QGIS 2.4.0 or ArcGIS 10.2. But first I need elevation data, information that is in AutoCAD extension  (.dwg, I presume) and when I use data-> export data and then save it as .shp I don't get elevation information. So I need to extrack the contourlines only or at least with elevation data per line.

Not sure if it's clear but I'll answer anything related to my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I export elevations from AutoCAD in a format that ArcMap can read?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75135/how-can-i-export-elevations-from-autocad-in-a-format-that-arcmap-can-read)

Comment: Do you have AutoCAD Map3d?  this answer is kind of the reverse using autocad.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16250/shapefile-attributes-to-autocad-annotation/16263#16263

Comment: If you don't find what you need. re-work the question and I can answer later.

Comment: @Brad Nesom, I don't have that program, but I have DWG true view, maybe is there a DWG free license software  to solve it?

Comment: No not really object data is proprietary. Does the prev comment answer? If not edit and vote to reopen

Comment: Not answers yet.

Comment: I have selested @tay bro answer as the solution but mine can be used as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into a similar item, though the line Elevation should be stored in *Elevation* field when opening the dwg in Arc:

[image]

From there, either by using, say, the ETGeowizards Shape to ShapeZ (free version tool) or running through Python you could set the elevation equal to this "elevation" field on import.  Otherwise if the contour elevations are stored as labels (this has been the case with some data from other depts) and not as the elevations themselves, it can take manual edits to find the annotation associated with that line and assign it the elevation.

Comment: So the idea is to export the file as a shapefile and then that tool? May I ask the adress of that tool @tay bro

Comment: Yes - export the Polyline of the DWG to Shape.  Then use the ETGeowizards tool on it (ETGewizards Toolbar -> Convert -> Shape to Shape(Z)) and make sure you select Elevation as your Z-field .  The free tools in here cover that functionality:  http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/gw_main.htm

Comment: I could found it  in the customization window, but I can't use any function. The only thing I see is the wizars logo but I can make it work. @tay bro

Comment: Drag the logo onto your main toolbar and access the tools that way.  You can click the logo from the toolbar (not the customization dialog) and the full toolset should appear.

Answer (score 1):

I've solve this question making use of a free licnese software called DraftSightx64. I just load the .dwg file on the program use the model view, go to:

Modify-> Decompose (Descomponer).http://prntscr.com/4lwpqx.

After this I save the .dwg and load it in ArcGIS desktop 10.2, then:

Open polilyne-> select the data I need-> data -> export data and then I can make a DEM.

Quite easy and using a free license tool, also all the information of contourlines remains on the lines. Maybe the same answer as @Brad Nesom, but usig a different software.